Kafka consumer registry takes a long time on each save
I'm quite new to kafka, I have an init function that sets up the producers, consumers and subscribes to all the topics I have. Currently its 20 topics for each of our express endpoints (res, req). It works all good, the only issue is that during development, on each file save it starts the consumer registry process again which takes around 30 seconds to load. Is there a way to cache the consumer registry once they happened for the first time. Is there a convention for this?
This is my init Kafka function:
export const initKafka = async () => {
  try {
    const kafkaClient = new Kafka({
      clientId: env.KAFKA_CLIENT_ID,
      brokers: env.KAFKA_BROKER_LIST,
    });

    const producer = kafkaClient.producer({
      allowAutoTopicCreation: true,
      createPartitioner: Partitioners.LegacyPartitioner,
    });

    await producer.connect();

    logger.log('Kafka producer is up and running');

    const consumer = kafkaClient.consumer({
      groupId: env.KAFKA_CLIENT_ID,
      sessionTimeout: env.KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS,
      heartbeatInterval: env.KAFKA_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS,
    });

    await consumer.connect();
    logger.log('Kafka consumer is up and running');

    const topics = Object.values(KafkaTopic);

    await Promise.all(
      topics.map((topic) => consumer.subscribe({ topic, fromBeginning: false }))
    );

    return { producer, consumer };
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`[KafkaInit] - Kafka error: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
};

And this is the main.ts file:
export let kafkaConsumer: Consumer;
export let kafkaProducer: Producer;

const app = express();

app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(helmet());
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: [env.CORE_FRONTEND_URL, env.CORE_ADMIN_URL],
  })
);
app.use(json({ limit: '5mb' }));


// Set the routes
app.use('/serverRoutes', routes);

app.listen(env.PORT, async () => {
  try {
    const { consumer, producer } = await initKafka();
    kafkaProducer = producer;
    kafkaConsumer = consumer;

    await registerConsumers(kafkaConsumer);
    logger.log('Kafka consumers are up and running');
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Error when initializing Kafka: ${error}`);
  }

  logger.log(`  Server is listening on port ${env.PORT}`);
});


And this is the consumerRegistry func (This what takes ages):
export const registerConsumers = async (consumer: Consumer) => {
  await consumer.run({
    eachMessage: handleMessage,
  });
};


and the handle message:
export const handleMessage = async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
  logger.log(`Received message on topic ${topic}`);

  const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message.value.toString());
  const consumerFunction = topicConsumerMapping[topic];

  if (consumerFunction) {
    try {
      await consumerFunction(parsedMessage);
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error(
        `[KafkaInit] - handleMessage - Error processing message from ${topic}: ${error}`
      );

      // DLQ Handling
      if (topic !== `${topic}-dlq`) {
        produceMessage(kafkaProducer, `${topic}-dlq`, {
          message: parsedMessage,
          key: message.key.toString(),
          partition,
          additionalHeaders: {
            error: error.message,
            clientId: env.KAFKA_CLIENT_ID,
          },
        });
      }
    }
  } else {
    logger.error(`No consumer function found for topic ${topic}`);
  }
};

We are using docker images for zookeper and kafka.
Here is the docker compose file for that:
# Kafka
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: 'platform-zookeeper'
    networks:
      - test-network
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    container_name: 'platform-kafka'
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest

    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    networks:
      - test-network
    volumes:
      - kafka-data:/var/lib/test_platform/kafka/data
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://:29092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://kafka:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    container_name: kafka-ui
    ports:
      - 9000:8080
    networks:
      - test-network
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: 'localhost'
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: 'kafka:29092'
      SERVER_MAXHTTPHEADERSIZE: '16384'
    depends_on:
      - kafka

